# Sparrow framework in not working on

Tags: iphone, sparrow-framework

I am using sparrow framework for my game development ,I downloaded the framework and installed the sparrow template but when I compile the code it gives following error.
Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.ADC_Reference_Library.DeveloperTools.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/CPlusTestReference/TestRun_h.

any help plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to link to a header file in the Apple Documentation sets.

Try putting the classes into your project directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Sparrow Framework it comes with a folder called Scaffold, which contains an XCode Project, ready to use. To use Sparrow in your games you should simply duplicate the scaffold folder and build on right there.